# How do I replace a sentence in shell?

Tags: regex, shell, replace, sed

I'm trying to find a way to replace a sentence within a text file in Shell,

For example, I want to replace **"Customer Name 1"** with **"customer name, jack _ 1"**.
I've included the special chars on purpose.

I understand `sed -i 's/original/new/g' file`

I'm looking for something that will replace more complex sentences that may include special characters.

Comment: Which special characters are you worried about? `sed` will handle most everything, though you need to be aware of any slashes in either the original or replacement text and treat those specially.  Newlines in the pattern are the other problem; do you have to worry about that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works just fine in sed...

```
$ sed 's/Customer Name 1/customer name, jack _ 1/g'
cust
cust
Customer Name 1
customer name, jack _ 1
```

(Odd lines are input, even lines are output.)

In general, if some of your symbols are misinterpreted, you can try escaping them by adding a backslash (`\`) before them.

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -i.bak -pe 's/Customer Name 1/customer name, jack _1/g;' [file(s)]
```

will do the same thing with in place editing of the file or files